# Most succint way to refer to a newly created object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have a function called on the click of a link within a TD. Upon clicking, I traverse back up the DOM to the TR that the link was within, then create a new TR after it.

So far so good.

Now that I've created that new TR, with a TD within, what's the best to now refer to that newly created TD. Or, do I need to traverse my way back into the new TD I created back from the original clicked object?

```
$("td.expandable a").click(function(){
    // figure out the number of columns we need to span
    var colspan;
    colspan = $(this).parents("tr").children("td").size();

    // insert the new TR
    $(this).parents("tr").after("<tr><td colspan=' & colspan & '></td></tr>");

    // **what syntax would I use here to refer to the above made TD?**

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("td.expandable a").click(function(){
        // figure out the number of columns we need to span
        var colspan = $(this).parents("tr").children("td").size(),
            tr = $("<tr><td colspan=' & colspan & '></td></tr>");

        // insert the new TR
        $(this).parents("tr").after(tr);

        // **what syntax would I use here to refer to the above made TD?**
        tr.find('td')

        return false;
});
```

You can also probably substitute `parents` with `closest` if you're updating *one* tr. An alternative yet more manual way would have been to do... `$(this).parents('tr').next().find('td')`

Comment: Wouldn't tr.find('td') batch all instances of that newly created TR? In my case, we might me inserting a bunch of these and would want to match only the one I just created. 

I may be misunderstanding 'parents'. Is that returning the parent TR or all parent TRs of the object as an array? If the latter, I think I need closest instead.

Comment: ah, indeed...I need to use 'closest' rather than 'parents' as I only one the single parent.

Also, on second read, I now realize that 'tr' isn't a string, but an actual jquery object, so that, indeed, will match that specific one. Thanks meder!

Answer (score 0):

insertAfter().wrap() are convenient for this type of thing:

```
$('td.expandable a').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var colCount = $parent.children('td').size();
    var $td = $('<td colspan=' + colCount + '></td>');
    $td.insertAfter($parent).wrap('<tr></tr>');
    return false;
});
```

I used the string concatentation operator "+". "&" is used for integers to calculate bitwise AND.